# Substitution theorem for definite integrals and indefinite integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, substitution, riemann-sum

Suppose we have the integral $\int_a ^b f(x)dx$ under what condition can we substitute $x=\phi(t)$ and write $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_\alpha^\beta f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$,where $\phi(\alpha)=a,\phi(\beta)=b$.I should say what is a sufficient condition that the above substitution is valid,also give me a counterexample where this does not hold.
What is the condition of the above to occur if $f$ is continuous and $\phi$ is also continuous?I want to understand why actually we can substitute because these are not taught in school level calculus,but as I am now in undergraduate level,I need to understand rigorously,so when we substitute $x=\sin t$ in a differential equation in an integral expression,we should know it actually is correct.

Also when can we substitute $x=\phi(t)$ in an indefinite integral?

Comment: @Thomas Does $dx$ or $dt$ have any separate meaning here?

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $\phi(t)$ is of the form $\phi(t) =\int_{\gamma}^{t} \psi(u) \, du$ for some $\gamma\in[\alpha, \beta] $ and the result is then written as $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\int_{\alpha} ^{\beta} f(\phi(t)) \psi(t) \, dt$$ This works if both $f$ and $\psi$ are Riemann integrable over $[a, b] $ and $[\alpha, \beta] $ respectively.

Comment: In simple terms your formula works if derivative $\phi'(t) $ is Riemann integrable on $[\alpha, \beta] $ and $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can substitute the variable if we can find a differentiable function $\phi(t)$ for which $f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t)$ is integrable over that interval. So a counterexample should be some $\phi$ continuous that does not meet the above conditions.

There's a good proof in Wikipedia, using only the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (I'm not reproducing it here since I'm on my phone) and the chain rule.

Comment: please give a counterexample in the answer.

Comment: I'm not at home now, so I'll cook up a counterexample later on. You could try finding it, probably involving $\phi(t) = \frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: when can we substitiute $x=\phi(t)$ in $\int f(x)dx=\int f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$

Answer (score 0):

The result is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus. If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ in the interval $[\phi(\alpha), \phi(\beta)]$, then the chain rule says $F(\phi(t))$ is an antiderivative of $f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t)$, hence the fundamental theorem implies
\begin{equation}
\int_\alpha^\beta f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) dt = F(\phi(\beta)) - F(\phi(\alpha))
=\int_{\phi(\alpha)}^{\phi(\beta)} f(x) dx
\end{equation}
You see that a simple condition is that $\phi$ is differentiable and that $f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$ and $f(x)$ are integrable with $F$ being an antiderivative of $f$.

In particular, the formula is true if $f$ is continuous in $[\phi(\alpha), \phi(\beta)]$ and $\phi'$ is continuous in $[\alpha, \beta]$.

Comment: Does $dx$ and $dt$ have own meanings here?

Comment: What if $f$ is continuous assumed?

Comment: $dx$ and $dt$ are only a notation due to Leibnitz. They don't have a special meaning here. You can see the formula $dx = \phi'(t) d t$ as a useful mnemonic.

Comment: when can we substitiute $x=\phi(t)$ in $\int f(x)dx=\int f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$

Comment: Again, $\int f(x)dx$ is only a notation to mean "an antiderivative of $f$", so when you write $\int f(x)dx = \int f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$, you're merely saying that when $x=\phi(t)$, then $F(x) = F(\phi(t))$, which is true if $\phi$ is differentiable.

Comment: How do I know that $\int f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$ would even exist?

Comment: What you know is that $(F(\phi(t)))' = f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$ hence the primitive exists.